# Jsoup - direct connect and connect through data object

Tags: jsoup

I got 2 different results when I use direct parameter and througt data object

---

### Test 1 : direct connect

```
String url = "https://wl-prod.sabresonicweb.com/SSW2010/B3QE/webqtrip.html?searchType=NORMAL&lang=en&journeySpan=OW&origin=NGO&destination=SGN&numAdults=1&numChildren=0&numInfants=0&promoCode=&alternativeLandingPage=true&departureDate=2013-12-27";

            Document doc = Jsoup
                    .connect(url)                    
                    .userAgent("Mozilla")
                    .get();
            Element tableE = doc.getElementById("dtcontainer-both");
            System.out.println(tableE.html());
```

--> Notice the last row : currency is JPY

---

### Test 2 : using data object

```
String url = "https://wl-prod.sabresonicweb.com/SSW2010/VNVN/webqtrip.html";
            Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<String, String>();
            data.put("searchType", "NORMAL");
            data.put("lang", "en");            
            data.put("journeySpan", "OW");
            data.put("origin", "NGO");
            data.put("destination", "SGN");
            data.put("numAdults", "1");
            data.put("numChildren", "0");
            data.put("numInfants", "0");
            data.put("promoCode", "");
            data.put("alternativeLandingPage", "true");
            data.put("departureDate", "2013-12-27");

            Document doc = Jsoup
                    .connect(url)
                    .data(data)                                        
                    .userAgent("Mozilla")
                    .get();
            Element tableE = doc.getElementById("dtcontainer-both");
            System.out.println(tableE.html());
```

--> Notice the last row : currency is VND

Could anybody tell me where I am wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your Urls are different:

```
1) "https://wl-prod.sabresonicweb.com/SSW2010/B3QE/webqtrip.html"
2) "https://wl-prod.sabresonicweb.com/SSW2010/VNVN/webqtrip.html"
```

Note: B3QE != VNVN

I did not test this, so you might have other things interfering as well...

Comment: if that helped you you should consider an upvote and also accept the answer to mark your question as solved.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your two URL paths are different: one contains B3QE and the other contains VNVN.